# How to activate and configure ElasticSearch Kafka Connect sink?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to setup Kafka in a Kubernetes cluster using helm.

I've used the [Confluent helm chart](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/cp-helm-charts/docs/index.html), which is quite complete, to install Kafka.

I then tried to see how [elastic Kafka connect sink](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/index.html#load-the-elasticsearch-connector) is configured. One point particularly strikes me : the `confluent load elasticsearch-sink` command. How can I have it done reproducibely when container is started ?
Furthermore, to configure elastic, I have to set a properties file. Am I right to use a [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) ? I'm however confused, because I'll have to change YAML configuration produced by helm, which doesn't seems so reproducable ...

Has someone any advice ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> One point particularly strikes me : the `confluent load elasticsearch-sink` command

The `confluent` command is meant to be used on `localhost` development / getting started envionments **only**. It therefore wouldn't know about Kubernetes (e.g. you would need an Ingress controller to expose the Connect REST API).

> Am I right to use a ConfigMap ?

I don't think that is correct. At least not outside of an Operator Framework for Kafka Connect (if one existed).

Connect is [configured through a JSON REST API](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/references/restapi.html).

Therefore, also isn't available to load a configuration at startup. It needs to be POST'd manually, then that config will be persisted in the `CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC` of Kafka.

Internally, `confluent load` is literally a `curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d${file} localhost:8083/connectors`

Comment: Yep, use the REST API, don't use `confluent` CLI, which is only for a single node, local install.